# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The report file not found.'

Tags: asp.net-core, dll, rdlc, filenotfoundexception, system.io.file

I am trying to use RDLC report in my ASP .NET Core project.

I have a method like-

```
public byte[] GenerateReport(string reportName, DbContext _dbContext)
        {
            string fileDirPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Replace("MyAPI.dll", string.Empty);
            string rdlcFilePath = string.Format("{0}Reports\\{1}.rdlc", fileDirPath, reportName);
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
            LocalReport report = new LocalReport(rdlcFilePath);
            var listData = _dbContext.UserInfo.Where(q => q.ID == "ABC").ToList();
            report.AddDataSource("DS", listData);
            var result = report.Execute(GetRenderType("pdf"), 1, parameters);
            return result.MainStream;
        }
```

I am getting the exception on `LocalReport report = new LocalReport(rdlcFilePath);` this line.

Why is the RDLC file **not found in the DLL**? I have tried cleaning, building & rebuilding my project lots of time; also tried a random .cs file instead of RDLC, but the exception is still there.

Can anyone please help me to find out what mistake I have made here & how to solve it?

Comment: Share your rdlcFilePath value

Comment: @Yorro `"G:\\Project\\API_Core\\MyAPI\\MyAPI\\bin\\Debug\\net5.0\\Reports\\TestReport(1).rdlc"`